# child_process.fork in node.js for synchronous calls

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, child-process

some Windows modules are broken for node-webkit, ex. win32ole, so I use a "proxy". At the start of nw.exe the script uses child_process.fork on a script with node.exe and runs till the end of nw.exe.

```
proxy = childprocess.fork('proxy.js', [], {execPath: __dirname+path.sep+'node.exe', silent: true});
```

All fine, but fork is completely asynchronous by using send(message) and on('message').
But I need a synchronous call with return value, something like:

```
var response = proxy.sendsync(<json or string>); // returns string or json
```

Or is there an other way for IPC (w/o network) between the node-webkit and a subprocessed node?

**Edit:** a simple example (no real code, only the idea) *win32ole doesn't work in node-webkit*

```
var archivename = oleproxy({type: 'get', name: 'ArchiveName'});
var config = loadconfig(archivename.result());
if (oleproxy({type: 'func', name: 'PrepareObj', paras: [config.maskid, config.rootobjid, 'caption']}).result() == 0) {
    oleproxy({type: 'set', name: 'ObjName', value: 'test'});
    ...
    oleproxy({type: 'set', name: 'ObjACL', value: '7a7'});
    var maskfieldcount = oleproxy({type: 'get', name: 'MaskFieldCount'}).result();
    for (var i=0; i<maskfieldcount; i++) {
    ...
    }
    ...
    oleproxy({type: 'func', name: 'SaveObj', paras: []});
}
```

The function `<json> = oleproxy(<json>)` is the wrapper function on the nw.exe side. It's send the json to the subprocess (script in node.exe). The subprocess make the real OLE call and get the call result. Now send the result back, but not via event. The main process is still waiting for the result.

Comment: Why do you need it to be synchronous?  It sounds like you just need to restructure the calling code so it can handle asynchronous.

Comment: It's a proxy for an OLE. The subprocess (node.exe) connect to an other app (3rd party App) at start and wait for commands by node-webkit. If the user click on a button than the nw.exe need information from the app, work with it, send commands to the app, which gives a return value, work with the return, next operation, ....

Comment: That does not explain why it needs to be synchronous.  Maybe some code would help?

Comment: Example added. The logic needs to be in the main process. A simple but ugly way would be http or websocket communication.

Comment: You'll need to do this asynchronously.  I don't see anything that wouldn't work that way.